# i have added menu item programmatically now how to call menu item on onClickmenuitem

Tags: android, menuitem

As i have added menu item pro-grammatically now i'm not getting that how will i apply cases on onClickmenuitem, as earlier Id was referenced of menu.

Below is the code as how i added menu

```
 menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Fullscreen").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: What will i give in place of id when applying cases on on Clickitem

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK provides following methods

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
invalidateOptionMenu()
```

Instead of adding menu item dynamically you can define the menu items in xml and show/hide the menu item from `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method.

Every time we call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` through the code in `Activity`, it Android system acknowledges that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated.

When menu options are recreated, a call is made to `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, where you can write code to show/hide different menu items as required.

Hope this gives you another way to workout a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you...

```
private static final int MENU_ID = 0xFEED;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ID, Menu.NONE, "FullScreen")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_ID:
        // handle event...
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pls follow this way

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 10:
        Toast.makeText(LoginPageActivity.this, "Now "+item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case 15:
        Toast.makeText(LoginPageActivity.this, "Now = "+item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case 20:
        Toast.makeText(LoginPageActivity.this, "Now == "+item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```